# Numero total de letras en un texto

Tags: python

Quiero sacar el numero total de letras que hay en un texto pero aun no he podido.

hasta ahora saque las veces que se repite cada letra pero no se como hacer para sacar el total de totas las letras que hay en el texto

mi código hasta hora

```
total = defaultdict(int)
with open("texto.txt", "r") as archivo:
    for linea in archivo.readlines():
        for letra in linea.lower():
            if letra.isalpha():
                total[letra] += 1

for letra, cuenta in total.items():
    print("Símbolo: ",letra,"|","Ocurrencias en el texto: ", cuenta)
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Necesitas contar el número de letras o de caracteres? Es decir, ¿Si el documento tiene espacios o símbolos de puntuación `.`. `,`, etc... los debes contar o ignorar?

Comment: el numero de letras, los demás caracteres ignorarlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea una variable que sume por cada letra

```
total = defaultdict(int)
suma = 0
extra = ',.'
with open("texto.txt", "r") as archivo:
    for linea in archivo.readlines():
        for letra in linea.lower():
            if letra.isalpha() or letra in extra:
                total[letra] += 1
                suma += 1

print(suma)
for letra, cuenta in total.items():
    print("Símbolo: ",letra,"|","Ocurrencias en el texto: ", cuenta)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio, si quiero sumar tambien los `.` y `,` como haria ?

Comment: En el `if` que agregé. Añade los caracteres en la variable `extra`

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS, ME SIRVIO MUCHO!!

Answer (score 1):

creo que se puede simplificar más... en python, un string es en realidad un "array" o lista, se puede sacar directamente el total de caracteres, por ejemplo:

```
>>> texto='en un lugar de la mancha'
>>> len(texto)
24
```

Si se quieren obviar ciertos caracteres, se pueden eliminar, por ejemplo los espacios:

```
>>> texto='en un lugar de la mancha'
>>> texto.replace(' ','')
'enunlugardelamancha'
```

Simplificando, para sacar sólo el total de letras:

```
>>> texto='en un lugar de la mancha'
>>> len(texto.replace(' ',''))
19
```

Un saludo.